# Can I connect my web app 1 to the websocket of my web app 2 c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, websocket

I am trying to create a realtime link between my 2 web applications developed in C# using ASP.NET MVC and websockets.

I would like to know if it is possible to do this as I need to develop a real time "notifications" system between my 2 applications and so far I have managed to implement websocket locally in only 1 of my web applications.

I appreciate your help in advance

Comment: Check out gRPC: https://grpc.io/docs/languages/csharp/quickstart/
This might be exactly what you are looking for.

Comment: thanks, right now I check it

Comment: the link between both applications works perfectly, thanks for your help!! :D

Comment: You're welcome :)